# how to combine filters in Django

Tags: python, django, filter

I have this code

```
 session_inicio = django_filters.Filter(lookup_type = 'gte',
                                               label = 'session_inicio',
                                               name='session_inicio')
```

And I woul like to include another condition on my query...

```
session_end = django_filters.Filter(lookup_type = 'lte',
                                               label = 'session_end',
                                               name='session_end')
```

in order to have something like this:

```
rangedates = session_inicio || session_end
```

Is it possible to do a stuff like this?

Comment: what is `Filter` (with the uppercase `F`)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe normal QuerySet object support those operators but

you can dynamically build a dictionary of `kwargs` and pass it using `**`

```
dynamic_lookup_dict = {}

if condition:
  dynamic_lookup_dict['session_inicio__gte'] = 'avalue'
elif other_condition:
  dynamic_lookup_dict['session_inicio__lte'] = 'avalue'

django_filters.filter(**dynamic_lookup_dict)
```